# Adding script to certain nodes and pages on drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to add a script code on all pages of my drupal except a few. Is there any conditionals I can use in html.tpl.php ?  or any functions on the template.php to achieve this?

I tried the code below on template.php but no luck :(

Thanks in advance!

```
 function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

  if (isset($variables['node']->type)) {
   $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . 
   $variables['node']->type;
  }

  //this is what I am trying
  if ($variables['nid'] == '77') {
   drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME') .'/scripts/path.js');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [hook_page_build(&$page)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_build/7.x)

```
function MYMODULE_page_build(&$page){

  $nids = array(123, 1234); // your nids 

  if(($node = menu_get_object('node', 1)) && in_array($node->nid ,$nids) ){
      drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mythemename') .'/scripts/path.js');
  }
}
```

Clear all cache after create this function to see result , also ensure of path script is correct ;)